# define class pointer in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class people
{
public:

   people* p;
   int x;
   people();
};
people::people()
{
   p = NULL;
}
void main()
{

    people jax;
    jax.p->x = 1;

}
```

---

i got this error

Unhandled exception at 0x00361419 in classarray.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

in this line
`jax.p->x = 1;`

help me pls !

Comment: `jax.p`is a null pointer, what do you expect what should happen when you try to access it?

Comment: better define constructor `people::people():p(NULL){}` for efficiency.

Comment: `void main()` is illegal in C++.

Answer (score 2):

you need to reserve memory for people:

```
void main()
{

    people jax;
    jax.p=new people;
    jax.p->x = 1;
    ...

    delete jax.p;

}
```

EDIT: 
in the end you need to free your memory, or your will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Other way is to implement special function for inner pointer initialization:

```
void people::init_p()
{
   if(!p) p = new people();
}
```